# Build eclipse plugin without IDE and without specifying a work space

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, ant, eclipse-pde

I want to know if it is possible to build an eclipse plugin **without** using the IDE and **without** specifiying a eclipse workspace.

Currently I have the following setup

**Build file for the plugin**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project default="plugin_export" name="build">
        <target name="plugin_export">
            <pde.exportPlugins destination="\export\" exportSource="false" exportType="directory" plugins="com.my.plugin" useJARFormat="true"/>
        </target>
    </project>
```

**Building plugin from console**

```
java.exe -jar
 "C:\Program Files\Eclipse_3.7.2_WIN32\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar"
 -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner
 -f "D:\source\com.new.plugin\build.xml"
 -data "D:\elipse_workspace"
```

I basically want to build the plugin WITHOUT specifying the **-data** parameter. Instead I would like to specify directly where the source is located...

Comment: If it is an option you can use [Tycho plugin](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) for maven

Comment: @Markus use the eclipse-pde tag unless you really mean Partial-Differential Equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify a workspace location. There is lots of information in the workspace metadata that is required during any build operation.

Comment: I was already pretty sure that this is true. Thanks for confirming it to me.

Comment: Does this mean it is impossible to build a plugin on a server that only stores the source code? I mean Im not going to put an eclipse workspace on my build server and keep updating that workspace when I want to make a build. I don't need to do this when I build a product so I'm confused here.

Comment: I already said you must have a workspace. How would the build know where to find all the dependent plugins? That info is part of the Target Platform which is in the workspace metadata.

Comment: Note: The Eclipse build systems for a full RCP (rather than a single plug-in) do work without a workspace, but require configuring with all the information that would have been in the workspace. It is also possible that Eclipse Tycho (which I don't use) may have something.